# Google Team Drive : List changes not giving any result if requested for particular team drive

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I tried using change id "1" too. But it returns empty result. 
However if searched for the whole drive (team drives and My drive) , it is working fine. 
I tried this on google API sandbox. Gives the same result.

Here is the code snippet i used.

```html
            List<Change> allteamdriveChanges = new List<Change>();
            ChangesResource.ListRequest req = _gdrive.Changes.List();           
            req.StartChangeId = (long)(Convert.ToUInt64(changeId) + 1);
            req.MaxResults = 1000;
            req.IncludeTeamDriveItems = true;
            req.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
            req.TeamDriveId = teamDriveId;

            do
            {
                ChangeList changes = req.Execute();

                foreach(var change in changes.Items)
                {                   
                        allteamdriveChanges.Add(change);
                }               
                
                currentChangeId = changes.LargestChangeId.ToString();
              
                req.PageToken = changes.NextPageToken;

            } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(req.PageToken));

            return allteamdriveChanges;
```

Can anyone look into this ?

Comment: and you got a watch notification that there were changes?  https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-revisions

Comment: Hi @DaImTo ,I myself added new files to the drive to test API.  
you can test the api to see my point. Changes when searched for particular team drive with any changeId , (say "1") does not return results.
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes

Comment: @DaImTo ..I am using v2 for now. But from the link you pasted still I couldn't clear my doubt.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-changes  I dont see where you are getting  changes.getStartPageToken

Comment: sorry , but i couldnt see getStartPagetoken anywhere in my code. Can you please specify more